# Sending A string of lat and long from mobile to server

Tags: android

android how to Send a String of data from an android mobile to server python what need to be modified in this android code

```
enter code here
  public void appendText(View view){
    Text.append( "\n  In chat ");

    try{
//  while (true)
    //{
    sentence=inputfld.getText().toString();
//  String sentence1=("hohohoh");
    Text.append( "\n  DataStream creating");        
    outToServer.writeBytes(sentence);
//      outToServer.writeBytes(sentence1);
    modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine(); 
    Text.append(modifiedSentence);
    inputfld.setText(null);
        }
         }
         catch(Exception modifiedsentence){
        Text.append("Exception");
    }


}

    RestClient client = new RestClient(webServiceUrl);
    client.addBasicAuthentication(username, password);
    try {
        client.execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        if (client.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            //return server error
            return client.getErrorMessage();
        }
        //return valid data
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(client.getResponse());
        return jObj.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return e.toString();
    }
```

So this to be added the Restclient is what i creat a new class for it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is RESTful, you might try using HTTPclient to post the data to the server and read the response.   If you use a REST abstraction layer like https://github.com/TylerSmithNet/RESTclient-Android (self promotion) then you can use the examples to get running in no time.

Comment: So this to be added the Restclient is what i creat a new class for it ???
 And what url web i put and the username ana password

Comment: If you take a look at the example, you'll see some possible techniques of utilizing the class.  You will just need to add the RESTclient package to your project and instantiate it as shown.