# Android error in sending data code

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending A string of lat and long from mobile to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144773/sending-a-string-of-lat-and-long-from-mobile-to-server)

```
enter code here
package andpy.ap;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;

  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
   import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

       import android.util.Log;

       public class andpy {

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

/* This is a test function which will connects to a given
 * rest service and prints it's response to Android Log with
 * labels "Praeda".
 */
public static void connect(String url)
{

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        // Examine the response status
        Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String result= convertStreamToString(instream);
            Log.i("Praeda",result);

            // A Simple JSONObject Creation
            JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);
            Log.i("Praeda","<jsonobject>\n"+json.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");

            // A Simple JSONObject Parsing
            JSONArray nameArray=json.names();
            JSONArray valArray=json.toJSONArray(nameArray);
            for(int i=0;i<valArray.length();i++)
            {
                Log.i("Praeda","<jsonname"+i+">\n"+nameArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonname"+i+">\n"
                        +"<jsonvalue"+i+">\n"+valArray.getString(i)+"\n</jsonvalue"+i+">");
            }

            // A Simple JSONObject Value Pushing
            json.put("sample key", "sample value");
            Log.i("Praeda","<jsonobject>\n"+json.toString()+"\n</jsonobject>");

            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }

     }
```

log cat

```
enter code here
05-27 01:42:07.728: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{andpy.ap/andpy.ap.andpy}: java.lang.ClassCastException: andpy.ap.andpy
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1848)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4338)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: andpy.ap.andpy
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
05-27 01:42:07.798: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(196):     ... 11 more
```

So that the error what am i doing wrong on the code ?!!

Comment: Your code does not contain any activity start. The error probably happens due to problem with starting activity. If you post more code it may be easier to give you an answer.

Comment: "So that the error what am i doing wrong on the code ?!!" Take a second to read that again and rewrite it so that it makes sense and is good English.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to my question in comments, I think you placed `andpy.ap.andpy` class in AndroidManifest.xml as activity.

However, it has nothing to do with Activity. You must extends Activity and use proper protocol to start the application (onCreate() etc). Please review documentation one more time.

In a nutshell, Android expects an activity and tries to cast your class to it.

```
/**
 * Perform instantiation of an {@link Activity} object.  This method is intended for use with
 * unit tests, such as android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase.  The activity will be useable
 * locally but will be missing some of the linkages necessary for use within the sytem.
 * 
 * @param clazz The Class of the desired Activity
 * @param context The base context for the activity to use
 * @param token The token for this activity to communicate with
 * @param application The application object (if any)
 * @param intent The intent that started this Activity
 * @param info ActivityInfo from the manifest
 * @param title The title, typically retrieved from the ActivityInfo record
 * @param parent The parent Activity (if any)
 * @param id The embedded Id (if any)
 * @param lastNonConfigurationInstance Arbitrary object that will be
 * available via {@link Activity#getLastNonConfigurationInstance()
 * Activity.getLastNonConfigurationInstance()}.
 * @return Returns the instantiated activity
 * @throws InstantiationException
 * @throws IllegalAccessException
 */
public Activity newActivity(Class<?> clazz, Context context, 
        IBinder token, Application application, Intent intent, ActivityInfo info, 
        CharSequence title, Activity parent, String id,
        Object lastNonConfigurationInstance) throws InstantiationException, 
        IllegalAccessException {
    Activity activity = (Activity)clazz.newInstance();
    ActivityThread aThread = null;
    activity.attach(context, aThread, this, token, application, intent, info, title,
            parent, id, lastNonConfigurationInstance, new Configuration());
    return activity;
}
```